# Outlook never connects to Exchange when CodedUI test is run by TFS Build Definition

Tags: c#, email, tfs, outlook, automated-tests

I am seeing an issue whereby the following code behaves differently in different situations:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        Process.Start("Outlook");
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

If the code is run on an agent by a TFS build definition, Outlook never connects to exchange (It says "DISCONNECTED" in the bottom system tray of Outlook. Any attempt to send emails result in them just sitting in the Outbox)
If I take control of the VM through MS Environment Viewer and click "Stop" in the MS Test Agent, once the code stops running, Outlook connects to Exchange without any user interaction (eg I do not have to hit Send/Receive).
If I run the code in the same VM, but triggered by a batch file in the startup folder (mstest /testcontainer:CodedUITestProject2.dll ), Outlook connects to Exchange just fine.

The MS Test Agent is running in "Interactive process" mode, not "Service" mode.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Is that really your entire `TestMethod`?  how would this ever complete?  For what reason is a codedUI test starting outlook?  I has a confuse

Comment: Yes, this is the entire method. The problem is not with the test "not completing", the problem is that outlook never gets into a "ready" state.

Comment: This is pared-down code. Ultimately the test code will be starting outlook, sending some emails, and verifying that they arrive in the expected state (eg arrives in correct mailbox, with message headers in expected state).
However, if I send emails from outlook using COM, outlook never sends the emails, they just sit there in the Outbox. However, it seems that the problem is nothing to do with the sending of the emails, as even if you just start Outlook and sit there doing nothing, Outlook does not connect to exchange.

Comment: Why are you trying to test Outlook?

Comment: I am not trying to test Outlook, I am trying to test an Outlook _plugin_

Comment: I have now managed to repro this issue on the dev env.  
If I run the tests as a TFS Build Definition on the dev env, I see exactly the same issue.  
So, same machine, same code, same user, same copy of Outlook, but when the tests run via the MS Test Agent, Outlook never connects.

Comment: Instead of adding a comments, you can also mark the reply as Answers if it fix your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the same with this issue on MSDN: [Microsoft Test Agent appears to be blocking Outlook connectivity to Exchange](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e5a9b73-3378-4c62-b26c-9038f50f6aec/microsoft-test-agent-appears-to-be-blocking-outlook-connectivity-to-exchange?forum=vsmantest)

And the investigation result:

> After installing fiddler I figured out what the problem was. The
>   Microsoft Test Agent was activating a proxy server which was blocking
>   connectivity to exchange. The proxy server was activated due to having
>   the ASP.Net Client Proxy for IntelliTrace and Test Impact turned on.
>
> Below is a link to the article with the exact same problem.
>
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecc0b342-8e4d-436c-90c2-5f11bce1e9d8/proxy-server-settings-being-set-automatically-which-is-causing-me-not-to-be-able-to-run-manual-test?forum=vsmantest

Comment: I can confirm that this solution worked for me.
Many thanks Eddie!